# How to detect mouse cursor is outside a windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I've written a code that dynamically creates a `POPUP` style window when the user clicks inside my main app window. Now I'd like the `POPUP` window to be automatically destroyed when the mouse cursor goes out of the POPUP wnd region. I know that i have probably handle the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message but how to do that? Please provide a simple code for that if You can...

Comment: I'd imagine `WM_MOUSELEAVE ` would be easier?

Comment: Indeed, you'll want to handle the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is helpful in detecting when the mouse cursor *enters* a window.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`WM_MOUSELEAVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseleave) message instead.  However, note that this message has to be explicitly requested via [`TrackMouseEvent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent), which your window can call when it receives its first `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.

Answer (score 0):

As @Remy Lebeau said, the following is the code implementation.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static BOOL Tracing = FALSE;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (!Tracing)
        {
            Tracing = TRUE;

            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme{};
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
            tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;

            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should set the `Tracing` flag from the return value of `TrackMouseEvent` function, like this: `Tracing = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);`. This way, if function fails, the tracing won't be erroneously set to true!

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the event.target and event.currentTarget, if both are same then you are out side of popup window else in side the popup window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).